# How to fetch specific data from a Firestore database on an activity after clicking on a specific marker in Mapview?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I created a fragment and took a Mapview on it. My Firestore database has a collection called Job Post1 which contains some documents and some fields in it. With that, I fetch Longitude and Latitude with the help of a marker shown on the Mapview.

What I want to do: after clicking on the marker on the Mapview, I want to show all fields in that document (the document from which i have plotted the marker with the help of longitude and latitude) on a Bottomsheet which I created.

What I did: I fetched the fields using documentsnapshot and in the updateBottomSheetContent() method I created a Strings and setText it.
After doing this, when I click on the marker, the hidden sheet is open and data fetch on it of his document but when I click another marker same data fetch instead of his own document. This is my problem.

My Java Code

```
package part.time.job.v2;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceResponse;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import model.Jobpost;
import model.Journal;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LabourFragment extends Fragment  implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapView mMapview;


    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    Dialog myDialog;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private View bottomSheet;
    private String title1;
    private String desc1;
    private String cate1;
    private String age1;
    private String vac1;
    private String loc1;
    private String jdate1;
    private String time1;
    private String whour1;


    FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference mOrderRef = mDatabase.collection("Job Post1");

    public LabourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_labour, container, false);
//        myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(120);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

        Places.initialize(getActivity(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
        mPlacesClient = Places.createClient(getActivity());


        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapview = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        if (mMapview!=null){
            mMapview.onCreate(null);
            mMapview.onResume();
            mMapview.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mGoogleMap=googleMap;

        FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference mOrderRef = mDatabase.collection("Job Post1");

        mOrderRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if(documentSnapshot.contains("lat") && documentSnapshot.contains("lon")) {
                        String lat = (String) documentSnapshot.get("lat");
                        String lon = (String) documentSnapshot.get("lon");
                        title1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("title");
                        desc1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("desc");
                        cate1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("category");
                        age1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("age");
                        vac1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("vacancy");
                        loc1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("location");
                        jdate1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("jobdate");
                        time1= (String) documentSnapshot.get("time");
                        whour1=(String) documentSnapshot.get("workinghours");

                            if(lat != null && lon != null && !lat.isEmpty() && !lon.isEmpty()) {
                            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
                            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon.trim());
                            IconGenerator iconGen = new IconGenerator(getActivity());

                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(title1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGen.makeIcon(title1))));
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 18.0f));

                            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                    marker.getTitle();

                                    updateBottomSheetContent(marker);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }
                }



            }

        });

         }

    private void updateBottomSheetContent(final Marker marker) {
        final TextView jobT = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.jobTitle);
       final TextView desc = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.jobDesc);
        final TextView cate = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.categ);
        final TextView age = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.ageLimit);
        final TextView vac = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.vacan);
        final TextView loc = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.locat);
        final TextView workingH = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.workingHour);
        final TextView date = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.jobDate);
        final TextView expire = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.jobExpire);
        final TextView uid = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.uid);
        final TextView time = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.timeStart);



        jobT.setText(title1);
        desc.setText(desc1);
        cate.setText(cate1);
        age.setText(age1);
        vac.setText(vac1);
        loc.setText(loc1);
        workingH.setText(whour1);
        date.setText(jdate1);
        time.setText(time1);


        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }


}
```

[This is Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqy6x.png)

Comment: Please post database structure

Comment: posted @ Ashish check in Question

Answer (score 0):

First You need to check whether the latitude that generated is existed in database fields or not. Check it out official documentation.

[Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Then if existed you will get the document id and you can use that.